# SwiftUI View not updating with binding to computed property on ObservableObject

Tags: swift, swiftui, state, textfield, observableobject

I have a very simple *SwiftUI* view that only shows a `TextField`. The text field's `text` is bound to the `string` property of my `viewModel` that I instantiate as a `@StateObject`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        TextField("Placeholder", text: $viewModel.string)
            .padding()
    }
}
```

The one thing that's "out of the ordinary" is that my `string` property is not a `@Published` property, but a simple computed property. In its setter, it sets the `displayedString` property to a fixed string (for testing purposes) which *is* a @Published property:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var displayedString: String = ""

    var string: String {
        get { displayedString }
        set { displayedString = "OVERRIDE" }
    }
}
```

So when I type a string into the text field, I would expect the setter to trigger a view update (as it updates a `@Published` property) and then in the view, the text field should be updated with the `displayedString`. So in other words: No matter what I type, the text field should always show the string `OVERRIDE`.

But that's not the case!

It works for the very first letter I type, but then I can freely type anything into the text field.

For example, if I launch the app with only this view and type the string
`123456789`
this is what is displayed on the text field:
`OVERRIDE23456789`

#### Why is that?

And how can I get the text field to always be up-to-date to what's set on the `viewModel`? (I know, I can just hook the text field to a `@Published` property directly, but I'm doing this computed property stuff for a reason and want to understand why it doesn't work as expected.)

---

#### Additional Observation:

When I add a `Text` label above the `TextField` and just make it show the `viewModel.string`, it shows the correct (expected) string:

```
var body: some View {
    Text(viewModel.string)
    TextField("Placeholder", text: $viewModel.string)
        .padding()
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Because `displayedString` is not changed after first time, ie `OVERRIDE == OVERRIDE` - no update event.

Comment: If you put `Text(viewModel.displayedString)` after it, you can see that `displayedString` is always "OVERRIDE" after the first letter. It looks like `TextField` is assuming that it is updating the computed variable, even though it can't. I would recommend making your own specialized `TextField` that handles whatever case you want.

Comment: @Asperi But the view itself *is* updated (as you can see in the "Additional Observation". The `body` closure is called again each time I type a character. So `TextField` must have some sort of an internal state I guess?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I have the same issue now.

Comment: No, but I would generally recommend not to use computed properties with test field bindings. Instead, you could try working with the `onChanged` modifier in your view (not tested for this purpose, but might be a good idea).

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure but I think a custom binding might work for you

In the ViewModel use

```
var string: Binding<String> { Binding(
    get: { displayedString },
    set: { displayedString = “OVERRIDE” } )}
```

Then in body use: viewModel.string instead of $viewModel.string in the TextField and use: viewModel.string.wrappedValue in the text view

Stuf

Comment: Oops. I forgot the _ in at the beginning of the set: in the binding

Comment: I tried that approach as well → same result. That made me assume that the `TextField` has an internal state that is sometimes not updates corrects – with or without bindings.